# How to shift items in a NSMutableArray

Tags: ios, nsmutablearray

I have a `NSMutableArray`. I am checking each item in the array 1 by 1 using a for loop and remove the current item. then I want to get the next index item into the 1st index. just like

Array = 1,2,3,4,5,6

Array = 3,4,5,6

I remove indexes using a for loop. How can I shift the next element to the removed index position

**UPDATED**

```
  for (int i=0; i<[m3u8 count]; i++) {

      NSString *str=[NSString stringWithFormat:
            @"http://cp2.comci.com:1000/server/default.stream/%@",
           [mutArrayMP3files objectAtIndex:i]
      ];
      [audioPlayer queue:str];
      [mutArrayMP3files removeObjectAtIndex:i];


    // Then here I want to make that array a continous one. 
    // Let's say it removed object at index 0, then 1st object should move to 0th location, 
    // 2nd should move to 1st.... likewise


}
```

Comment: This question is rather unclear. Perhaps post some code you've tried to write?

Comment: Post your relevant code in your question.

Comment: arrays don't work as regular arrays in say C. if you remove [1,2] from your `NSMutableArray` you will be left with [3,4,5,6]. NSMutableArray gives you this for free,

Comment: If I understand your question, this is the normal behavior of a mutable array. When you remove an item any items with a higher index is moved forward. From the docs, "To fill the gap, all elements beyond index are moved by subtracting 1 from their index."

Comment: But when I remove the item at index i It gives this exceptionCount 3
2014-12-16 12:09:22.770 Hiru FM new[9901:1135124] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 2 beyond bounds [0 .. 1]'
*** First throw call stack:

Comment: That's because you only have 2 items in the array when you try to access an item at index 2. That has nothing to do with the question you are asking.

Comment: @rdelmar Granted, I'm not sure I understand the question, but yeah, it kind of does have something with the OP's issue. The OP's using [m3u8 count] to iterate over the mutArrayMP3files array, and I'm guessing mutArrayMP3files is a copy; but with the modifications to mutArrayMP3files, [m3u8 count] can extend beyond the mutArrayMP3files indices...

Comment: Warning: I'm half asleep right now. I might have a more coherent response in the morning if you still need an answer then. But I'd recommend clarifying your question in the meantime.

Comment: @user2889249 So you want to make your array go from Array = 1,2,3,4,5,6 to Array = 3,4,5,6? Is that what you want to accomplish? You want to remove the first two indices?

Answer (score -1):

You cannot modify an NSMutableArray while you're in the midst of iterating over it. And if you are shrinking the array as you loop, then you can't keep incrementing the index you use or you will "run off the end" eventually. What you can do is make a copy, and modify that; or, use a `while` loop instead of an iterator:

```
NSMutableArray *array = @{@1, @2, @3, @5, @6};
while([array count]) {
    NSNumber firstElement = [array firstObject];
    // do something with firstElement;
    [array removeObjectAtIndex:0];
}
```

The problem with your current code is that you will end up trying to reference items in your array with an index out of bounds, because the array is getting smaller as you go. Here's how you could tweak it with code closer to the OP:

```
// assumes [m3u8 count] equals original size of mutArrayMP3files
for (int i=0; i<[m3u8 count]; i++) {

  NSString *str=[NSString stringWithFormat:
        @"http://cp2.comci.com:1000/server/default.stream/%@",
       // this line would have crashed:
       // [mutArrayMP3files objectAtIndex:i]
       [mutArrayMP3files objectAtIndex:0]
  ];
  [audioPlayer queue:str];
  // this line would also have crashed
  // [mutArrayMP3files removeObjectAtIndex:i];
  // remove the object that was processed, all other objects "shift down" one index
  [mutArrayMP3files removeObjectAtIndex:0];
```

}

Comment: you can remove object from an NSMutableArray if you use the `reverseObjectEnumerator`

Comment: sure, but I'm trying to warn of a common pitfall. Sometimes it's convenient to get the objects in original order, and OP seemed to want to pop the objects as they were processed.

Comment: why the downvote? given OP's attempt now shown, a `while` loop is an appropriate solution and the answer is on point.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but the op is already using a separate variable for the loop count vs the array used for editing: [m3u8 count] vs mutArrayMP3files